# How could you grab an avatar from Gravatar?

Tags: php

Is there a way with PHP to get the Avatar from the Gravatar website?

Comment: WebApps.SE is for users of web applications, php questions may fit better at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/

Answer (score 1):

```
$hashemail = md5( strtolower( trim( "MyEmailAddress@example.com " ) ) );
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php echo $hashemail; ?>.jpg" />
```